# How to open Apple Maps from another app

Tags: ios, macos

My company created an app that sends location deals in an app inbox.  I want to send directions in the appmail so that if someone clicks on 'Click here for directions' it will automatically open directions from current location to the requested point in the Apple `Maps` app.

When I email the URL to myself and open it with AppMail, it works perfect.

When I send the URL via AppMail, it opens the URL in safari via `GoogleMaps`.

[This](http://maps.apple.com/?q=daddr=2351%20Noblestown%20rd%20Pittsburgh,%20PA&saddr=current%20location) is the URL I'm using.

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=2351%20Noblestown%20rd%20Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;saddr=current%20location">&gt;&gt;Click Here for Directions&lt;&lt;</a>
```

Comment: check out this https://discussions.apple.com/message/23603501#23603501

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?...
```

To one of:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?...
or
http://maps.google.com/maps?...
```

The apple.com URL is technically the correct one, but the google URL is the only one that will work properly on older versions of iOS, and new versions of iOS also support it as well (although I don't know how long that will last).